# How to show subtotals in first checkout step?

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, totals

I want to add the subtotals to first checkout step "**shipping**" into the sidebar.
In the `checkout_index_index.xml`

I can see the totals but I have no clue why it is not loading in the first checkout step.

Answer (score 10):

All of these solutions imply that you need to copy the `abstract-total.js` to your own theme, but this is not necessary. Even more so: it might introduce new problems as soon as a Magento update decides to update the original `abstract-total.js`.

A better (more unobtrusive) solution to this is to make use of a [RequireJs mixin](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/javascript-dev-guide/javascript/js_mixins.html). This way you can extend a JavaScript object provided by Magento and only add your own adjustments:

In `view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/abstract-total-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In `view/frontend/web/js/abstract-total-mixin.js`:

```
define([], function () {
    "use strict";

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            /**
             * @return {*}
             */
            isFullMode: function () {
                if (!this.getTotals()) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Now you have the same results in an upgrade-safe way ;-)

Comment: Thank you! I can confirm this works on 2.3.1 and the shipping totals are also updated when the method is changed

Comment: Awesome! This works :) thank you

Answer (score 4):

I had a similar issue and this is the way i managed to get it working.

You can override the following file

> app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/abstract-total.js

and update isFullMode function to return

> true

instead of

> return stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');

```
isFullMode: function() {
        if (!this.getTotals()) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }
```

Full code of overriden abstract-total.js file

```
/**
 * Copyright © 2016 Magento. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
/*global define*/
define(
    [
        'uiComponent',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
        'Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals',
        'Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator'
    ],
    function (Component, quote, priceUtils, totals, stepNavigator) {
        "use strict";
        return Component.extend({
            getFormattedPrice: function (price) {
                return priceUtils.formatPrice(price, quote.getPriceFormat());
            },
            getTotals: function() {
                return totals.totals();
            },
            isFullMode: function() {
                if (!this.getTotals()) {
                    return false;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
    }
);
```

Hope it helps

Comment: Worked for me, but it dose not update shipping price if I change shipping methods, like if I am on cartpage, selected "freeshipping-0.00$" & proceed to checkout, now on checkout page#shipping tab it shows default selected "freeshipping-0.00$", thats good(in working condition), but when on same page#tab I select another method like selected "Homedelevery-10.00$" in sidebar nav it shows "Homedelevery-0.00$", So it updates shipping method name/title but not price & also not calculating totals(ajax not called), Any solution for that @St0ik

Answer (score 2):

In addition to enabling the `full mode` for the cart summary, you want to make sure its shipping price, taxes and grand total get refreshed when picking/changing shipping methods during that first step.

You can copy the following file to your theme (don't edit it directly):

> module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js

Add the `Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/estimate-service` to the list of dependencies like so:

`define([
    'jquery',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote',
    'Magento_Checkout/js/model/cart/estimate-service'
], function ($, Component, quote, estimateService) {
    'use strict';
    //...`

Source: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/176238/62137

Answer (score 1):

Basically its not magento default functionality to enable total summary in shipping step.
So we have to change some of files.

Let's follow below steps:

**Step:1** 
To enable summary override below file.

> app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/abstract-total.js

override  **isFullMode()**

```
 isFullMode: function() {
            if (!this.getTotals()) {
                return false;
            }
           // return stepNavigator.isProcessed('shipping');
            return true;
        }
```

**Step:2** 
 To change shipping price value on selection of the shipping method You can override the following file.

> app/code/Magento/Checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/summary/shipping.js

change **getValue()** function.

```
getValue: function() {

                if (!this.isCalculated()) {
                    return this.notCalculatedMessage;
                }
                //var price =  this.totals().shipping_amount; /* comment this line and add below two lines. */
                 var shippingMethod = quote.shippingMethod();
                var price =  shippingMethod.amount;
                return this.getFormattedPrice(price);
            }
```

It is working (y).

Comment: Great Work, But Order Totals Not Updating on Shipping method Selection.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe it is interesting to take a look at the Clean Checkout module which simplifies the checkout and also adds the subtotal to the shipping step.

https://github.com/danslo/CleanCheckout