# Magento 2 - How can I show subtotal on checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, magento-2.2.5, subtotal

On checkout page I want subtotal, shipping and grand total in both "**Shipping**" and "**Payment**" steps.

I have followed this https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/235329/31910 :

In `view/frontend/requirejs-config.js`:

```
var config = {
    config: {
        mixins: {
            'Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total': {
                'Vendor_Module/js/abstract-total-mixin': true
            }
        }
    }
};
```

In `view/frontend/web/js/abstract-total-mixin.js`:

```
define([], function () {
    "use strict";

    return function (target) {
        return target.extend({
            /**
             * @return {*}
             */
            isFullMode: function () {
                if (!this.getTotals()) {
                    return false;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
    }
});
```

After this I have got **Shipping** amount and **Grand total**, but there is no subtotal appearing.
[image]

My question is, **How can I show subtotal in checkout?**

Answer (score 0):

I have create the custom module and get the subtotal value Please check code hope help you,

**Mage/Subtotal/Block/Checkout/Quoteinfo.php**

```
<?php

namespace Mage\Subtotal\Block\Checkout;

class Quoteinfo extends \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template 
{
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template\Context $context, 
        \Magento\Checkout\Model\Session $checkoutSession, 
        array $data = []
    )
    {
        parent::__construct($context, $data);
        $this->_checkoutSession = $checkoutSession;
    }
    public function getQuoteData()
    {
        $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote();
        if (!$this->hasData('quote')) {
            $this->setData('quote', $this->_checkoutSession->getQuote());
        }
        return $this->_getData('quote');
    }
}
```

**Mage/Subtotal/etc/module.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Module/etc/module.xsd">
    <module name="Mage_Subtotal" setup_version="2.0.0"/>
</config>
```

**Mage/Subtotal/view/frontend/layout/checkout_index_index.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>

<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <block class="Mage\Subtotal\Block\Checkout\Quoteinfo" before="" cacheable="false" template="Mage_Subtotal::checkout/quoteinfo.phtml">
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

> Set Your right position.

**Mage/Subtotal/view/frontend/templates/checkout/quoteinfo.phtml**

```
<?php
$quote = $block->getQuoteData();
//Get subtotal and grand total of customer current cart
?>
<div class="subtotal">
<?php echo __('Cart Subtotal'); ?>
<?php echo $subTotal = $quote->getSubtotal(); ?>
</div>
```

**Mage/Subtotal/registration.php**

```
<?php
\Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
    \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
    'Mage_Subtotal',
    __DIR__
);
```

> > Cart subtotal value move your right position

I hope help you

Thanks.

Comment: you code is good, it will show subtotal in content, but I don't want to show subtotal anywhere in content, instead I want to show subtotal at the top of totals block. Which is I guess magento default functionality, but it is not appearing on my website